# How to verify table update and migrate data from another table - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, verification, data-migration

I have following two tables in my potgres database with each type.

user

```
userid       | bigint (PK) NOT NULL
username     | character varying(255)
businessname | character varying(255)
```

inbox

```
messageid    | bigint (PK) NOT NULL
username     | character varying(255)
businessname | character varying(255)
```

What i wanna achieve here is i want to add a new field called `userRefId` to `inbox` table and migrate data on `user` table's `userid` data into that where each `username` and `businessname` match in both tables.

These are the queries i use to do that.

```
ALTER TABLE inbox ADD userRefId bigint;

UPDATE inbox 
SET userRefId = u.userid
from "user" u
WHERE u.username = inbox.username 
AND u.businessname = inbox.businessname;
```

Now i want to verify the data has been migrated correctly. what are the approaches i can take to achieve this? (Note : the `username` on `inbox` can be null)

Would this be good enough to verification?

Result of `select count(*) from inbox where username is not null;` being equal to

`select count(userRefId) from inbox;`

Answer (score 1):

Is the data transferred correctly?  First, the update looks correct, so you don't really need to worry.

You can get all rows in `consumer_inbox` where the user names don't match

```
select ci.*. -- or count(*)
from consumer_inbox ci
where not exists (select 1
                  from user u
                  where ci.userRefId = u.userId
                 );
```

This doesn't mean that the `update` didn't work.  Just that the values in `consumer_inbox` have no matches.

Under the circumstances of your code, this is equivalent to:

```
select ci.*
from consumer_inbox ci
where userId is null;
```

Although this would not pick up a `userId` set to a non-matching record (cosmic rays, anyone?).

You can also validate the additional fields used for matching:

```
select ci.*. -- or count(*)
from consumer_inbox ci
where not exists (select 1
                  from user u
                  where ci.userRefId = u.userId and
                        ci.username = u.username and
                        ci.businessname = u.businessname
                 );
```

However, all this checking seems unnecessary, unless you have trigger on the tables or known non-matched records.